# How to query multiple data from one table into categories base on data name in another column?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Good day everyone, this is one of those areas that is a little over my head, so I have not written anything.

I have a table in MS Access that holds phone numbers.

I would like to query the phone numbers so that the Result Set places the numbers in categories based on the data name in another column.
Example: If Phone Type is CP, I would like to query it to a Category in the result set name Cell phone.

Please see this screen shot:

[image]

Thanks everyone!

Guy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the crosstab query wizard. It will guide you through building the query you want.

Comment: I tried using the Cross Tab but instead of getting phone numbers in the Phone type column, I am getting calculations. In the last section, I am ask what numbers to calculate. I am not performing calculations, this is why it is giving me the amount of phone numbers rather than the actual numbers in the column.

Comment: @UnaverageGuy Use First, not Sum or Count. You can paste the SQL into your question, above, if you are having problems.

Comment: Thank you! I got it but there is one problem, I already have the user ID from another table. The Cross Tab wizard Requires that I select a Row Header. Can I do away with the Row Header, or can I make the Row header in the Select statement not show up in the query result?

Comment: @UnaverageGuy It seems to me you are confusing data and presentation. If you must present your data in a query rather than a form or report, you can make the width of the first column zero.

Comment: Thank you, I have it all figured out - never heard about Cross Tab before this post! :)